# Update Record field through LWC button click

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

Can you please assist with below

Trying to update account status from apex class through button click

```
import { LightningElement,api,wire,track } from 'lwc';
import getCheckedStatus from '@salesforce/apex/CCNBCustomSettingsHandler.getCtosBlackListCheck';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { updateRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import blackListedStatus from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Status__c';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
import ID_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Id';
export default class BlackCheckfromApex extends LightningElement {
@api recordId
@track status
fields = [blackListedStatus];
@wire(getCheckedStatus)acStatus;
handleNewClick(event) {
    getCheckedStatus({selectedAccId: this.recordId})
        .then(result => {
            this.status = result;
            console.log(this.status);
            console.log('Hey');
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.error = error;
        });

        const allValid = [...this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input')]
            .reduce((validSoFar, inputFields) => {
                inputFields.reportValidity();
                return validSoFar && inputFields.checkValidity();
            }, true);
            console.log('allValid');

            if (allValid) {
                // Create the recordInput object
                const fields = {};
                fields[ID_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.Accountid;
                fields[blackListedStatus.fieldApiName] = this.template.querySelector("[data-field='Status__c']").value;

                const recordInput = { fields };

            updateRecord(recordInput)
                .then(() => {
                    console.log(recordInput)
                    this.dispatchEvent(
                        new ShowToastEvent({
                            title: 'Success',
                            message: 'Contact updated',
                            variant: 'success'
                        })
                    );
                    // Display fresh data in the form
                    return refreshApex(this.acStatus);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    this.dispatchEvent(
                        new ShowToastEvent({
                            title: 'Error creating record',
                            message: error.body.message,
                            variant: 'error'
                        })
                    );
                });
            }
        else {
            // The form is not valid
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Something is wrong',
                    message: 'Check your input and try again.',
                    variant: 'error'
                })
             );
        }
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need both:

```
@wire(getCheckedStatus)acStatus;
```

and

```
getCheckedStatus({selectedAccId: this.recordId})
```

Choose one.

Also,

```
const allValid = [...this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input')]
```

will run before

```
getCheckedStatus({selectedAccId: this.recordId})
```

Because the call is asynchronous. Indenting your code the way you have may mislead people into thinking this code runs from front to back. It does not.

To fix it, you can use async/await:

```
async handleNewClick(event) {
  let result = await getCheckedStatus({selectedAccId: this.recordId});
  // ... rest of code
```

Almost all of your other problems stem from these two main issues. Also, if you're using lightning-record-edit-form, you could save yourself some trouble building the UI with lightning-input-field.

Comment: Thanks You!

Yes I'm using lightning-record-edit-form

<template>
    <lightning-card>
         <div>Hi</div>
         <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Account"
         record-id={recordId}>
         <lightning-message>
         </lightning-message>
         <div>{status}</div>
         <lightning-button
             label="Apexy Fetch"
             title="Apexy Fetch"
             onclick={handleNewClick}
             variant="Success">
         </lightning-button>
        </lightning-record-edit-form>
    </lightning-card>
</template>

Comment: Tried the above as per your comments but still , the status not getting updated

Since I'm pretty new to LWC, can you please assist

Thanks in Advance!